# Object dependencies and interaction

Tags: c#, oop

**EDITED:**

I am diving into OOP concepts but when I think I figured it out in my head I get confused again in practice.

I have created two classes:
Light (represents a light bulb)

```
public enum LightState { ON, OFF }

public class Light
{
    private LightState _state;

    public LightState CurrentState
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }

    public Light() : this(LightState.OFF) { }

    public Light(LightState state)
    {
        CurrentState = state;
    }
}
```

Switch, which should change the state of light bulb.

```
public class Switch
{
    private Light _light;

    public LightState State
    {
        get { return _light.CurrentState; }
        private set { _light.CurrentState = value; }
    }

    public Switch(Light light)
    {
        _light = light;
    }

    public void TurnLightsOff()
    {
        if (State.Equals(LightState.OFF))
        {
            PrintState(LightState.OFF);
        }
        else
        {
            State = LightState.OFF;
        }
    }

    public void TurnLightsOn()
    {
        if (State.Equals(LightState.ON))
        {
            PrintState(LightState.ON);
        }
        else
        {
            State = LightState.ON;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get the interaction part, is it done right in my example?

Let's say I introduce another class `Man`, who can turn switch ON/OFF, how should then `Man` object change the state of `Switch`?

Comment: `Man` would call `TurnLightsOff()` or `TurnLightsOn()` from an initialized `Switch`

Comment: Why not create a enum for state instead of an int with a strange validation with a list. Too complex for its purpose

Comment: A switch controls a single light bulb, but a man can control multiple switches. The relationship is almost the same. OO wise speaking.

Comment: I'm getting a strange sence of deja vu with this question

Comment: @SamIam What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` is superfluous here. Put the methods into `Light` and act on it

```
public class Light 
{
    ....
    public void Flip()
    {
       if( CurrentState == LightState.ON )
       {
           CurrentState = LightState.OFF;
       } else {
           CurrentState = LightState.ON;
       }   
     }
}
```

The a man can act on the light

```
public class Man
{
    ....
    public void TurnLightOn(Light light)
    {
        light.CurrentState = LightState.ON;
    }
    public void FlipLight(Light light)
    {
        light.Flip();
    }
}
```